# Regular expression to match text between <a ..> and </a>

Tags: java, regex, string

Could anyone be able to give a regular expressiont to match the link text between `<a> and </a>` tags in a HTML snippet.

Sample data: `<a href="link.html">Link Title</a> - 15 comments <br/> <a href="otherlink.html">Some other Title</a> - 6 comments`

Requirement: I need to extract only the link texts (i.e. the one between `<a> and </a>` - *Link Title* and *Some other Title*) to use in my application.

Please note that the link text might contain non-english characters and all possible puncutations also. I tried using '.' operator, but since it does a *greedy* match, it matches the entire text between first `<a>` and last `</a>`. But I want only the link texts.

Any help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<a[^>]+>(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="url/?that=<breaks>&things">oops</a>`

Comment: Yes, right, but even parsers can breakable with crafted invalid html too.

Comment: But this isn't invalid HTML. It's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 6):

Stop using regex to 'parse' html.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Go use a real parser.

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Comment: I say that with love, tough love.

Comment: i have written my own parsing logic in a conventional way (substring, indexOf, etc) - but it's a requirement to use the regular expression. :(

Comment: A requirement to use a regex? ok.  Well, the link above has plenty of excellent parsers, please don't write your own, and here is example code to parse out URLs from anchor tags from about 4 of them: http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed literally dozens of times already on StackOverflow (and thousands of times in other fora), but apparently it *still* needs repeating: **it can't be done**.

Regular Expressions can only parse Regular Languages. HTML is *not* a Regular Language. Proving that you cannot parse HTML with Regular Expressions is a regular (pun intended) homework assignment on pretty much every college and university on the planet. It has been proven by literally tens of thousands of people. It is as watertight as any mathematical proof can be. It is a very short, very simple, very approachable proof. There is no way that anyone will be able to find a hidden flaw in it, because the proof is so simple and small that there is plainly nowhere a flaw *could* hide.

Oh, and did I mention **it can't be done**?

This is not the Traveling Salesman Problem, where it takes a *very long time* to run. It is not P=NP, where we don't know whether it is true or not.

This is genuinely, absolutely, 100%, positively, totally, provably impossible.

I forgot. Did I already mention **it can't be done**?